# Elasticsearch: Simple autocomplete returning matching terms for a field (of particular docs)

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch

I am a bit green to elastic search so bear with me.

I have documents indexed with a simple 'string' type field and a few other simple fields.  The field "value" will have potentially a very large string.

I want to search for terms to present the user as they type (not search for the document, but for suggestions to search upon).  I want these suggestions to be individual terms that were tokenized for the field 'value' for all documents that match a query.

Something like, give me the docs that match 'id:my_id' and give me back the top 5 terms that start with the letters 'hellow' looking in the field 'value'.

Do I really have to index this field specially (autocomplete) to simply get a list of matching words (terms)?  I have a feeling I missing the forest for the trees here.

I'm talking if I have a field with 60,000 words, if I simply wanted to return the top 5 words that matched as they typed, do I need to setup the autocomplete type?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the 'completion' field type and manually using an analyzer to populate the completion input/outputs before indexing with the context option.  It works, it's fast, but feels very dirty having to analyze outside of ES and then store the data twice ('value' field and completion field).  Wish I could do it in one step; something like tell ES to analyze field 'value' and use it as the 'completion' input/output.